# Syntax error on token "+"

Tags: java, syntax, double, token

I'm a new Computer Science student and I'm writing my first program that is using multiple classes.

However, I'm getting an error with the `getAddition()` method, using all double values it won't actually allow me to add them together.

```
public class SodaCanClass {

    private double SodaCanHeight;
    private double SodaCanRadius;
    private double SodaCanAddition;

    public double getSodaCanHeight(double height) {

        SodaCanHeight = height;
        System.out.println("Soda Can Height is: " + SodaCanHeight); 
        return SodaCanHeight;
    }


    public double getSodaCanRadius(double radius) {

        SodaCanRadius = radius;
        System.out.println("Soda Can Height is: " + SodaCanRadius); 
        return SodaCanRadius;
    }


    public void getAddition(double height, double radius){

        SodaCanHeight = height;
        SodaCanRadius = radius;
        SodaCanHeight + SodaCanRadius = SodaCanAddition;   //<---- ERROR HERE

    }

}
```

Comment: In Java it works the way round: `SodaCanAddition = SodaCanHeight + SodaCanRadius`

Comment: Write it on the other side.

Answer (score 1):

On the left hand side, there can only be the variable name like SodaCanHeight.
The right hand side holds the value. So you can write

```
SodaCanHeight = SodaCanRadius + SodaCanAddition
```

The right hand side will be calculated first and then saved into the variable given on the left side.

It can be confusing since most of us are used to read from left to right, but in this case you need to read from right to left :)

(sometimes you'll see things like

```
a += b
```

which is equal to

```
a = a+b
```